# Integers with numberf

Tags: ios, xcode

I have this code:

```
sliderPosition.minimumValue = 150.0f;
sliderPosition.maximumValue = 450.0f;
```

it works as if the range was 150 to 450. so I cant understand what is the "f"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just write like `150.0` it'll be taken as a `double`.
If you write it like `150.0f` it'll be taken as `float`.

In situations where you need to tell the compiler that you are using float not double you need to put a `f` after the number.